# html / css: create hole in a div

Tags: jquery, css, html

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is a hole in the middle of a div. Behind there is a 100% width div that will eventually be a scroller, over the top will again be a 100% width div, but with a hole in the middle to show through the content from underneath. At the minute I've achieved this using a transparent png background image, but the `.test` div behind will need to be clickable so I'm trying to find a better solution.
jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/vmTHL/1/ 
HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 240px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.background-image {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; height: 240px; 
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 2; 
    background-image:url('http://oi42.tinypic.com/2ziwodd.jpg'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"
}
```

Visually this is what I'm after, but the `.test` div needs to be clickable too, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try putting it inside the div, and put the content u want in the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out a solution to this problem, it may not be the best, but it works as I wanted it to:
jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/vmTHL/7/ 
HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="background-image">
    <div class="bg-left"></div>
    <div class="bg-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.background-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 240px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: orange;
}
.bg-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 240px;
    padding-left: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-top: -240px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.bg-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 240px;
    padding-right: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    margin-top: -240px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

As you can see, the red of the `.test` div always stays at a consistent width, and is still clickable, as was what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use two DIVs. One for the left side and one for the right side. They need to have a width < 50% for the hole between them.

Comment: yes this is a solution I'd thought of previously, although working width percentage widths won't quite work as the hole needs to be a fixed width, if I used 2 percentage width divs either side, the size of the hole will always be changing.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the z-index value for `.test` higher than `.background-image`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmTHL/2/)

Also you have extra `"` at last of `.background-image`. Remove that.

Or do you want like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmTHL/4/)?

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%; height: 240px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 40%;

}

.background-image {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; height: 240px; 
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 2; 
    background-image:url('http://oi42.tinypic.com/2ziwodd.jpg'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: the `.test` div underneath needs to be 100% width, as it is eventually going to be a slideshow slider, I just need a hole / viewport in the `.background-image` div above to show the content below

Answer (score 0):

You can give .test  more z-index so that it comes on top. And adjust its placement by using left & right as the position is absolute.

Try This :

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto; height: 240px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: pointer;
    left:30%;
    right:30%;
}

.background-image {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; height: 240px; 
    top: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 3; 
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: nice solution, although the hole in the middle needs to stay at a consistent size, thus the reason using percentage widths isn't right for this

Comment: If that's the case i think you can always use fixed widths :)

Comment: yes but then the size of the hole in the middle changes size, visually I need to achieve what I've got in the jsfiddle I posted, just a solution that allows the `.test` div underneath to be clickable

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/vmTHL/6/          Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: not quite, the amount of red (i.e. the amount of the `.test` div you are seeing) is always changing. e.g. in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/vmTHL/1/ there is a 125px viewport where you can see the red underneath. That is what I'm after, but without using a transparent png like I have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38722/discussion-between-mak-and-user1374796)

Comment: you didn't reply on chat earlier?